# curl doesn't return response or http code after several times it does

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, httprequest, telegram

I want to send many request to a website and f‌ind the id of last post that exist. 
As my host hits the limit of requests to that websites after several requests, I expect the curl request to return an error so that I can save the last post's id in my database and continue scrolling later.
But after about 200 successful requests, curl doesn't return any response nor http code.
To be specific I want to get posts of a telegram channel from an id to the end.
Here is the function that I have written for this purpose:

```
function get_post_html_content($channel_username, $message_id){

  try {

    error_log($message_id."\n");

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
      "https://t.me/".$channel_username."/".$message_id."?embed=1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin';
    $headers[] = 'Origin: https://t.me';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!$content) {
      $errno = curl_errno($ch);
      $error = curl_error($ch);
      error_log("Curl returned error $errno: $error\n");
      curl_close($ch);
      return false;
     }
  $http_code = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

  error_log("http code: ".$http_code."\n");

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }

  $content = gzdecode($content);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $content;
}
```

The problem is after several time that http code 200 printed in error log file and this function returns the content, Suddenly it doesn't print any http code in error log and even doesn't return false so than I can save last post id in database.
So how can I change this function to return false in this situation?

Comment: They probably have a rate limit unless you get a premium account.

Comment: @Barmar How can I change it to return false?

Comment: I read your question more carefully, and now I don't really understand what's happening. If the server doesn't respond in a minute the timeout should occur and you'll report that error.